# Spring Boot server giving 404 for images

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've been trying to figure this out for two days now. I've looked at least 6 stackoverflow posts regarding the issue and no suggestions have worked. I have a google login button in my html with a .png image. The web page loads but the image shows a 404 response code. The image file is located in src/main/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/images/. I am omitting code not pertinent to this problem to shorten the post.

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // Register resource handler for CSS and JS
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());

        // Register resource handler for images
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/images/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
    }
}
```

```
    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**/*.png");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login","/login*", "/logout*", "/signin/**", "/signup/**", "/customLogin",
                        "/user/registration*", "/registrationConfirm*", "/expiredAccount*", "/registration*",
                        "/badUser*", "/user/resendRegistrationToken*" ,"/forgetPassword*", "/user/resetPassword*",
                        "/user/changePassword*", "/emailError*", "/resources/**", "/old/user/registration*","/successRegister*",
                        "/oauth/**", "/qrcode*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/images/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/invalidSession*").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/user/updatePassword*","/user/savePassword*","/updatePassword*").hasAuthority("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE")
                .anyRequest().hasAuthority("READ_PRIVILEGE")
                .antMatchers("/*","/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/tokens/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                //.defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html")
                //.defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8080/foos/1")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                //.successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                .authenticationDetailsSource(authenticationDetailsSource)
            .permitAll()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
                .maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).and()
                .sessionFixation().none()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(myLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .invalidateHttpSession(false)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.html?logSucc=true")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
             .and()
                .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices()).key("theKey")
             //.and().csrf()
                //.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**/*.png").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
    // @formatter:on
```

In html page:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = '/spring-security-oauth-server/login/google';">Login with Google<img src="googleLogin.png"></button>
```

Comment: Can you please check your network tab and put update your question with the requested URL? I assume it is doing relative

Comment: the requested url is http://localhost:8081/spring-security-oauth-server/googleLogin.png

Comment: I believe it suppose to be `/images/googleLogin.png`

Comment: I tried that too but doesn't work. Ive tried placing the file in various suggested locations and updating MVCConfig but not working

Comment: Are you able to make `http://localhost:8081//images/googleLogin.png` work. Make that work, then change URL

Comment: I tried making a direct request in the browser with my server context and all the possible urls and it gives 404

Comment: also its not redirecting me to the login page so I know HTTPSecurity isn't blocking the request